# Copy embedded PDF dates metadata to the actual file timestamps

Tags: windows-10, pdf

What I'm looking to do is very simple yet I haven't found a tool to do it on Windows.

I want to pick a PDF file and copy it's "CreationDate" and "ModDate" metadata into the actual file modified and created timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more search I found that [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) can do exactly this with two simple commands.

To copy the creation date:

```
exiftool "-FileCreateDate<CreateDate" <FILE/FOLDER>
```

To copy the modified date (it is also applied to the accessed date):

```
exiftool "-FileModifyDate<ModifyDate" <FILE/FOLDER>
```

If you don't want symlinks to be resolved it needs `-i SYMLINKS` at the start, also `-r` to be recursive, i.e.:

```
exiftool -i SYMLINKS -r "-FileModifyDate<ModifyDate" <FILE/FOLDER>
```